# Is there any Spy++ equivalent for linux/x window?

Tags: linux, x11

Spy++ is a tool for windows that let the user spy on windows attributes, child windows and the message that it will process. It is handy utility to debugging UI related code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Back then, i tested my middle mouse button using a tool called `xev`. It creates a new window, which you can send events (by clicking on it, or pressing buttons) which are catched and printed on stdout. According to a comment by jpalecek, it can also be used to watch other windows, instead of a new one. The following will watch events from a window you selected by clicking on it:

```
xev -id $(xwininfo | awk '/Window id/ { print $4 }')
```

For gathering general information, xwininfo can be used, which can display children, attributes and more.

Comment: xev is likely the closest equivalent to Spy++ on X11, but it is much lower level than what OP is probably looking for, and is somewhat unlikely to help in debugging UI code (unless that code is written to use Xlib directly, which is very improbable).

Comment: I guess this is the closest, but it is too primitive.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen a "spy" feature from [Squish](http://www.froglogic.com/pg?id=Products&category=squish&sub=overview&subsub=overview).  This is a GUI testing tool.

Answer (score 0):

[WinFormSpy](https://bitbucket.org/hindlemail/winformsspy/wiki/Home) provides some of the basic features provided by Spy++ for winform applications running using mono.

It allows viewing certain windows attributes and shows the window structure as a tree.